# Vala files import

Tags: linux, oop, vala

I have a problem when work with properties in separated files in Vala Language

The **Main.vala** file is

```
using Teste;
using Cagado;

static int main(string[] args)
{   
   GUI gui = new GUI();
   stdout.printf("%d\n", gui.idade);
   return 0;
}
```

The **HelloVala.vala** is:

```
namespace Teste
{
    public class Person : Object
    {
        private int _age = 32;

        public int age
        {
            get { return _age; }
            set { _age = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

The **Cagado.vala** is:

```
using Teste;

namespace Cagado
{
    public class GUI : Object
    {
        Person _person = new Person();
        _person.age = 35;
        private int _idade;

        public int idade
        {
            get { return _idade; }
            set { _idade = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

When i compile this code, the compile gives me the message error:

```
Cagado.vala:9.15-9.15: error: syntax error, expected identifier
    _person.age = 35;
                ^
```

I program in C# and this not happened in C# oriented object system.
Someone could explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
public class GUI : Object
{
    Person _person = new Person();
    _person.age = 35; // <--
    ...
```

You can't put arbitrary code inside of the class itself, only declarations.  What you need to do is something like

```
public class GUI : Objects
{
    Person _person = new Person();
    construct {
        _person.age = 35;
    }
```

You could also modify add a constructor to the Person class:

```
namespace Teste
{
    public class Person : Object
    {
        private int _age = 32;

        public int age
        {
            get { return _age; }
            set { _age = value; }
        }

        public Person(int age) {
            GLib.Object (age: age);
        }
    }
}
```

Then do

```
public class GUI : Object
{
    Person _person = new Person(35);
```

Comment: Thanks for help me ^_^.  I wonderered for 3 days in what problem i doing. You could answer me if Vala works diferently from C# in this feature?

Comment: I'm not certain (my C# is pretty minimal), but I would be surprised if C# were any different from Vala in this respect.  Java isn't, nor is C++…